# How capture scene when it is opening?

Tags: android, andengine

My code capture scene : But `onScreenCaptured` execute when I have to exit scene (click button Back). How capture scene when it is opening?

```
public void TakeScreenShot() {
    String filename = Utilities.getDateTimeNow() + ".png";
    String FileName = Environment
        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        + "/" + filename;
    Log.d("Screen", " Path " + FileName);
    ScreenCapture screenCapture = new ScreenCapture();
    scene.attachChild(screenCapture); // Attaching screen capture after all
                                      // rendered.
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = MainActivity.this.mRenderSurfaceView.getWidth();
    int height = MainActivity.this.mRenderSurfaceView.getHeight();
    screenCapture.capture(width, height, FileName,
        new IScreenCaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScreenCaptured(final String pFilePath) {
                Log.d("Screen", "Yes " + pFilePath);

                // UpImageToFB(pFilePath);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + pFilePath),
                        "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScreenCaptureFailed(final String pFilePath,
                    final Exception pException) {
                Log.d("Screen", "NO " + pFilePath + "    " + pException);

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: load all resources of scene first.Then load this scene in engine.After that call the screen capturing code.it will work.

Comment: this scene had load ok, But i call capture screen when i click menu back on my phone, it go to onScreenCaptured.

Comment: i didnot got it.Can you please explain clearly.But what i got is that you want to add  screenshot to  your scene.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture screen, then call captureScreen() method after loading scene.
Now you want to send this captured screen uri to other activity on clicking back button.If so, 
call this Intent  on clicking back button